# JS files not showing content on network tab even if status is 200

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, dynamic, load

I am trying to load the `vendor.bundle.js` file dynamically using the below code. I see all other files getting loaded properly but the `vendor.js` shows in Network Tab of Chrome *200 Status* and on Response it Says `"Failed to Load Response Data"`.

Due to which the code is not getting executed and the page is not rendering anything.

Here are stuffs which may be needed:

- Angular Version : 2.4
- "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1"
- JIT build

Attached is the image what I see in chrome Inspect.

[image]